# Set User Status as Logged out when Program is closed In Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have written a method which sets the status (1) (logged in) when user login.

```
public void updateLoginStatus(String n) {
    conn = DBConnection.ConnectionDB();
    String loginStatus = "UPDATE `login` SET `status`=1 WHERE username = ?";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(loginStatus);
        pst.setString(1, n);
        pst.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

There is another method when the logout button is clicked the user status is set to 0 (logged out)

```
public void updateLogoutStatus(String n) {
    conn = DBConnection.ConnectionDB();
    String loginStatus = "UPDATE `login` SET `status`=0 WHERE username = ?";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(loginStatus);
        pst.setString(1, n);
        pst.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

This works fine, However, when a user clicks the red cross on menubar in the database it shows that the user is logged in but I want to set it to log out. I have found a method 
onsetDefaultCloseOperation() but couldn't figure it out what to do. I am a beginner please help.

Comment: what user is logged in? of your application? maybe you should start by closing your connections

Comment: when the user presses the login button on my application I set their status to 1 (status I a column in database which takes boolean data), when they click logout button their status is set to 0 but when they uses the red cross button on the menu bar(default close button ) the status remain logged in

Comment: just remove that button. or replace it by one you create yourself. or change the default behavior of that button (not sure if that's an option)

Comment: if I remove the default button that won't be user-friendly, I just have to grab the default action behavior and implement it in my way

Comment: why wouldn't that be user friendly? who says the user even has to notice?